# How to compare and highlight date (with some condition) in DataTable?

Tags: javascript, date, datatable

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            var date = new Date();
            var date_now = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            var date_compare = (new Date(aData[10]) < new Date(date_now) ? true : false);
            console.log(date_now);
            console.log(aData[10]);
            console.log(date_compare);
            if(date_compare == true) {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#ff8080');
            }
            else {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'none');
            }
        },
```

This isn't working.

This coding is in the view inside javascript aData[10] is from model, the SQL look like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DB.TGL_JATUH_TEMPO, '%d-%m-%Y') AS TGL_JATUH_TEMPO
```

This is the result

[image]

The result I want is 
true
true
false

I want to compare like this
if the date from my SQL Table < today's date
then highlight red the column

The problem is the date compare didnt work

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: can you add console values also

Comment: What is the point of using `new Date()` to create a Date, then use the parts to generate another date? If you want the start of "today", then `var date_now = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)` will do the job in the above for the sake of comparison. Note that *date_now* will be a time value, not a Date object but it will work fine in comparisons with Dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with this line

```
(new Date(aData[10]) < new Date(date_now)
```

Its not converting to Date format. 
If you can pass Date format as "YY-MM-DD" eg: 2010-12-25 this might work

```
var dateVar = "2010-10-30";
var d=new Date(dateVar);


var currDate = new Date();
if(d < currDate){
        alert("Entered Date is less than current Date");
}else{
        alert("Entered Date is greated than current Date");
}
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NRz97/531/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the format of your date strings is not recognized by the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so it's always returning `null` so they will be always **equal**, that's why your test always fail.

You need to build the Date object correctly, to respect the [RFC2822 specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) so the `Date` can be parsed by [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

This is an example of how you could build your `Date` objects:

```
var d1 = "25-03-2018";

var date1 = new Date(d1.substr(d1.length - 4), d1.substr(3, 2) - 1, d1.substr(0, 2));
```

**Demo:**

This is a Demo with date comparison:

```js
var d1 = "25-03-2018";
var d2 = "26-03-2018";

console.log(d1.substr(d1.length - 4));
console.log(d1.substr(3, 2));
console.log(d1.substr(0, 2));


var date1 = new Date(d1.substr(d1.length - 4), d1.substr(3, 2) - 1, d1.substr(0, 2));

var date2 = new Date(d2.substr(d2.length - 4), d2.substr(3, 2) - 1, d2.substr(0, 2));

console.log(date1 < date2);
```

Comment: That should be `d1.substr(3, 2) - 1` for the month parameter as months are zero indexed. If `d1 = "31-01-2018"` and `d2 = "01-02-2018"` then `d1 < d2` returns false. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yes you are right, I had this in mind ;) I just forgot it. Thank you for pinting it out.